# Scenebuilder has no ButtonBar

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, efxclipse

I'm starting to work with SceneBuilder and want to add a ButtonBar. But the interface doesn't show the ButtonBar.

I am using SceneBuilder 2.0.

I can add the ButtonBar in the FXML file manually.

How can I add the ButtonBar in SceneBuilder?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was that I downloaded from Oracle. Now I found out that I needed the one from Gluon, there I can add the ButtonBar.